# Need to add XML namespace prefix in only one XML element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmlnode, nsxmlelement

I am trying to generate an XML with namespace prefix in one element out of few using XMLSerializer.

Below is the code -

```
var commRemision = new Contracts.Dtos.Remision();
Transformer transformedRequest = new Transformer();
commRemision = transformedRequest.TransformRequest(dgRemision);

public const string ElementNamespace = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52";

XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlNamespace.Add(string.Empty, ElementNamespace);  ///remove default namespaces

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(commRemision.GetType(), ElementNamespace);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false); // no BOM in a .NET string
settings.Indent = true;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, commRemision, xmlNamespace);
    }
}
```

And the class structure -

```
public class Remision
{
    [XmlElement]
    public InfoBasica InfoBasica { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public Addenda Addenda { get; set; }
}

public class InfoBasica
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int folio { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Addenda", Namespace = Addenda.ElementNamespace)]
public class Addenda
{
    public const string ElementNamespace = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2";

    [XmlElement(Namespace = ElementNamespace)]
    public List<AddendaBuzonFiscal> AddendaBuzonFiscal { get;set;}
}

public class AddendaBuzonFiscal
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Emisor")]
    public AddendaEmisor Emisor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public AddendaReceptor Receptor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need my XML to be like this -

```
<Remision version="5.2" xmlns="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52">
<InfoBasica folio="10240" />
<Addenda>
<ns:AddendaBuzonFiscal version="2.0" xmlns:ns="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2">
<ns:Emisor telefono="8787826600" />
<ns:Receptor telefono="1234567" />
<ns:TipoDocumento nombreCorto="FAC" />
</ns:AddendaBuzonFiscal>
</Addenda>
</Remision>
```

but unable to add the ns prefix in the elements. What I am able to generate is this -

```
<Remision version="5.2" xmlns="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52">
<InfoBasica folio="10240" />
<Addenda>
<AddendaBuzonFiscal version="2.0" xmlns:ns="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2">
<Emisor telefono="8787826600" />
<Receptor telefono="1234567" />
<TipoDocumento nombreCorto="FAC" />
</AddendaBuzonFiscal>
</Addenda>
</Remision>
```

Please note that I need namespace prefix only in the AddendaBuzonFiscal tag not in every tag of the XML.

Please help.

Comment: Your second bit of XML is *not* what you will generate - it would be `xmlns=".."` in `AddendaBuzonFiscal`, not `xmlns:ns=".."`.  Given that, the two are semantically identical. You need to provide the reason as to why this isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Add prefix alias to `XmlSerializerNamespaces`

```
xmlNamespace.Add("ns", "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2");
```

Comment: Thanks.. It was a great help but a small glitch. This code is adding the second namespace with the top tag (Remission) and I want the namespace in the AddendaBuzzonFiscal tag.

Comment: Now my top tag looks like this - <Remision xmlns:ns="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2" version="5.2" xmlns="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52">
and bottom one like this -  <ns:AddendaBuzonFiscal version="2.0">

Comment: @AbhinavSingh - It doesn't matter for the parser, where the declared namespace.

Comment: Actually not for the parser but for the third party service. The service is not accepting the 2 namespaces in the Remission tag and throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your own xml serialization logic instead of relying on `XmlSerializer` for such a namespace declaration like that:

```
public abstract class XmlSerializationBase : IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return default(XmlSchema);
    }

    public virtual void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class InfoBasica
{
    public string Folio { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Emisor")]
public class Emisor
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "telefono")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Receptor")]
public class Receptor
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "telefono")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TipoDocumento")]
public class TipoDocumento
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nombreCorto")]
    public string NombreCorto { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AddendaBuzonFiscal", Namespace = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2")]
public class AddendaBuzonFiscal
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Emisor", Namespace = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2")]
    public Emisor Emisor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Receptor", Namespace = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2")]
    public Receptor Receptor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TipoDocumento", Namespace = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2")]
    public TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class Addenda : XmlSerializationBase
{
    public AddendaBuzonFiscal AddendaBuzonFiscal { get; set; }

    public override void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Addenda");

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddendaBuzonFiscal));
        var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("ns", "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, AddendaBuzonFiscal, namespaces);

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

public class Remision : XmlSerializationBase
{
    public InfoBasica InfoBasica { get; set; }

    public Addenda Addenda { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

    public override void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Remision", "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("version", Version);
        writer.WriteStartElement("InfoBasica");

        writer.WriteAttributeString("folio", InfoBasica.Folio);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        Addenda.WriteXml(writer);

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

and the code to generate xml no longer uses serializer:

```
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false); // no BOM in a .NET string
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        var commRemision = new Remision
        {
            Version = "5.2",
            InfoBasica = new InfoBasica { Folio = "10240" },
            Addenda = new Addenda
            {
                AddendaBuzonFiscal = new AddendaBuzonFiscal
                {
                    Version = "2.0",
                    Emisor = new Emisor { Telefono = "8787826600" },
                    Receptor = new Receptor { Telefono = "1234567" },
                    TipoDocumento = new TipoDocumento { NombreCorto = "FAC" }
                }
            }
        };

        using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
                {
                    commRemision.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
                }
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```